# Properly formatting box and whisker data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm doing some social media reporting for my company, and want to look at the statistical distribution of Twitter posts. The dependent variable is the engagement rate (defined as a %) and the various independent variables could be hour of day, day of week, number of hashtags used, etc.

I have an Excel export with all of my tweets, one row per tweet, with columns showing the variables. I am having mixed success getting a Box and Whisker plot to function correctly. Do I need to re-format my data? If so, how? If not, what am I doing wrong?

For example, my data might look like this:

```
HOUR OF DAY    ENGAGEMENT %
08             1.02
17             0.98
12             1.88
```

But the box plot doesn't like that :(
[Twitter Hour of Day Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBOUm.png)

I was able to hack together a version for Day of Week, but this involved me manually re-ordering the first few rows to get the x-axis in line for Mon, Tue, Wed, etc.

```
DAY   ENGAGEMENT %
Thu   0.89
Mon   2.02
Tue   1.69
etc.
```

[Twitter Day picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUnH5.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm unclear about what you want.  The data table in your first image does not appear to have a Day of Week field, so you would not be able to have that in your chart.  If the second image is what you want your chart to look like, then your data WILL have to include DOW info.